# Does Lucee support any single character wildcards in QoQ?

Tags: coldfusion, lucee, qoq

ColdFusion query of queries syntax honors underscore as a single-character wildcard, and escaping of literal underscores with square brackets:

```
LIKE '_abc' -- any 1 char then abc
LIKE '[_]abc' -- actual underscore char then abc
```

Lucee (5.1 tested) doesn't appear to honor the wildcard, or the escaped version to match a literal underscore. Behavior is the same with or without cfqueryparam.

Does Lucee have a single character wildcard for QoQ, and if so, how do you escape that character when you want to find that actual literal?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by escaping the underscore using the "at" character, e.g.

```
LIKE '@_@abc' escape '@'
```

Comment: Turns out that Lucee 5.1 crashes if you use NOT LIKE and ESCAPE together: Encountered "ESCAPE" at line [...]. Was expecting one of: "AND" ... "CONNECT" ... That's what my code does, so I didn't think ESCAPE was supported at all. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @enigment - Try the above, but put the NOT before the column name: ie `WHERE  NOT Col LIKE '@_@abc' escape '@'` . [Seems to work](http://trycf.com/gist/69c450d1d18772853cb30e086ddabe5c/lucee5?theme=monokai).

Comment: Well I'll be, you're right, that works, in both ACF and Lucee. Never knew that was legal SQL even.

Comment: @enigment - IIRC, I got it from SQL Server, which also [supports that syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189455.aspx). Granted, I find `WHERE Col NOT LIKE ...` a bit more intuitive in SQL, but I guess it is not that different from using `!` for negation in CF, ie `if (!someCondition) {....`.

Comment: I get the idea, didn't know it applied in that form to SQL. LSNED :)